# boost ipc warning - on inclusion of managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, boost-interprocess

Hi I get the following warnings

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -c -I/usr/local/boost_1_53_0 -I/home/aditya/CodeBase/includes      MAIN.cpp 
In file included from /usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp:15:0,
             from /usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess /managed_shared_memory.hpp:22,
             from MAIN.cpp:22:
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp: In function  ‘void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::thread_sleep(unsigned int)’:
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp:169:65: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(ms / 1000u)’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘__time_t {aka long int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp:169:65: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘((ms % 1000u) * 1000000u)’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘long int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

on compiling the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

int main(){

   return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc 4.7 on an ubuntu 12.04